# Respond to NodeJS prompt inside of Mocha test

Tags: node.js, unix, mocha.js

I am attempting to write some test in Mocha for a Command Line NodeJS application I wrote.

The Node application will prompt the user for a URL.  It then takes the URL, parses it for CSS, JS, and Image files and downloads them into their respective directories.

I'm having trouble getting the testing set up as the application is dependent upon user input, and I cannot figure out how to programmatically send keystrokes back to the prompt.

My URL request inside the Node application functions basically like this:

```
rl.setPrompt('Please enter URL: ');
  rl.prompt();
  rl.on('line', function(line) {
    url = line;
    rl.close();
  }).on('close', function(){
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error) {
        /* Do some stuff here */
      } else {
        throw new Error('Err making initial HTTP request. Attempted: '+url);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

And my test currently looks like

```
var child = require('child_process');
var assert = require("assert");


describe('System', function(){
  before(function(){

  });
  it('should run successfully', function(){
    child.execSync('node index.js', function(error, stdout, stderr){
      //console.log(stdout);
    });
  });
});
```

The test current instantly fails as it cannot run without the user input.  Should this be synchronous maybe?  I just can't find anything on how to wait and respond to a prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract a function that you can actually test. So it should look something like this:

```
rl.setPrompt('Please enter URL: ');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', function(line) {
  url = line;
  rl.close();
}).on('close', function(){
  parseUrl(url); 
  });
});

...

function parseUrl(url){
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
      /* Do some stuff here */
    } else {
      throw new Error('Err making initial HTTP request. Attempted: '+url);
      return false;
    }
}
```

Now you have a small function `parseUrl` which you can test very easily. Just pass a test URL and you're done.